# How to Issue /Mint / Generate additional tokens? Contract is mintable

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

I have Token on ropsten network (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x975FB1824F82E446DD3F5c4cb04474468ED7d878) which is Mintable with initial supply of 10B and Mintable Cap up to 50B.

My ether account (owner) has only 10B, I now want to start MINTING/GENERATING additional tokens, let's say add 20B more tokens.

**How do I do that?**

[1] some important codes of my contract:

```
   constructor() public {
           name = "PPT";
           symbol = "PPT";
           initialSupply = 10000000000;
           totalSupply_ = initialSupply * 10 ** uint(decimals);
           balances[owner] = totalSupply_;
           mintCap = 50000000000;
           emit Transfer(address(0), owner, totalSupply_);
       }
```

[2] some important codes of my contract:

```
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner public returns (bool) {
           require(mintCap >= totalSupply_.add(_amount));

           totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.add(_amount);
           balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
           emit Transfer(address(0), _to, _amount);
           return true;
       }
```

Comment: What tools are you using to interact with your contract? Should be as simple as calling `mint()` with the `owner` address and valid `_to` and `_amount` parameters

Comment: I am using a terminal/truffle, how can I call those functions? @ShawnTabrizi

Comment: This should probably be the more general question "How do I interact with a deployed contract?".

Comment: Please specify which version of OZ you are using. Also, both your coding snippets suggest that you are trying to do yourself what's already implemented in OZ. For example, in the constructor, assuming you inherit from `ERC20`, you can simply call `_mint(owner, 10000000000 * 10 ** uint(decimals))`.

Comment: As @RichardHorrocks suggested I better ask "How do I interact with a deployed contract?"

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to answer my own question, so if there are people still confused here is the answer:

1) open https://remix.ethereum.org
2) create a file token.sol
3) select compiler matching your token.sol (in my case 0.4.23)
4) paste original code to the window
5) press compile
6) Go To “RUN” 
7) Select token.sol
8) list of Functions will appear, past values needed and click on the name of functions!

That's it!